# google cloud vision category detecting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, vision

I want to use google cloud vision API in my android app to detect whether the uploaded picture is mainly food or not. the problem is that the response JSON is rather big and confusing. it says a lot about the picture but doesn't say what the whole picture is of (food or something like that). I contacted the support team but didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a custom classification, not specifically raw Cloud Vision annotation.

Either use the https://cloud.google.com/automl/ or invent an own wheel like I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55880316/322020